# Where can I find library installed by Tex live utility on Mac?

Tags: mactex, tex-live-utility

I wanted to install [kpathsea](https://ctan.org/pkg/kpathsea) (to be able to use LaTeX in python) which cannot be installed separately and can only be installed via [Tex Live Utility](https://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/). I have already installed [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) and downloaded Tex Live Utility, in it kpathsea is shown as installed (the x86_64-darwin version, that is). The question is, where can I find the `libkpathsea.o` file so that I can link it to configure other installations?

Comment: `tlmgr info --list kpathsea` will list all files installed on your system. Anyway, I have troubles understanding, what you are trying to do. Maybe you could explain why you need `libkpathsea.o` to "use LaTeX in python"?

Comment: I believe shared libraries are disabled for distribution, so you'll have to compile it yourself. See `--enable-shared` on the [build page](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlbuild.html).

Comment: @zyxwl2015, I found your question in the hopes that someone had done what you have set out to do (use kpathsea from Python). Have you pursued this? (I fully understand if the answer is "no")